# Fill new column in one dataframe with values from another, based on values in two other columns? (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need to add a column to a dataframe and fill it with values from another dataframe, but I do not have a unique ID or key or index that is shared between them. They do have two identifiers in common that make each row unique between them, and I want to try and match on both those columns.

Here is an example...

```
Student ID  Test Day        Student ID  Test Day    Grade
E0304003    Quiz 1      E0304003    Quiz 1  A
E3305002    Quiz 1      E0303003    Test 2  A
E0303002    Test 1      E0304005    Quiz 2  D
E0304004    Quiz 1      E3306001    Test 1  C
E0301001    Quiz 1      E0301001    Quiz 1  A
E0307002    Test 2      E0307002    Test 2  C
E0303003    Test 2      E0308002    Quiz 2  A
E0304005    Quiz 2      E0301002    Test 2  C
E3306001    Test 1      E3305002    Quiz 1  C
E0308002    Quiz 2      E0303002    Test 1  F
E0301002    Test 2      E0304004    Quiz 1  C
```

I want to create a third column in the first set that is also Grade, and contains the same values for rows that match the student ID and Test Day in the other dataframe.

You can see that the column order in each set doesn't match, and in the real data, there will be missing values, so I need this to be dynamic; it's not as simple as just sorting and then matching.

Can I do something like:

```
For row in df_one:
        if df_one["Student ID"] == df_two["Student ID"] and df_one["Test Day"] == df_two["Day"]:
                df_one["Grade"] = df_two["Grade"]
        else:
                df_one["Grade"] = "Unknown"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join and if some values not match get `NaN`s, which are replaced by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df_one, df_two, on=['Student ID','Test Day'], how='left')
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].fillna('Unknown')
print (df)

   Student ID Test Day Grade
0    E0304003   Quiz 1     A
1    E3305002   Quiz 1     C
2    E0303002   Test 1     F
3    E0304004   Quiz 1     C
4    E0301001   Quiz 1     A
5    E0307002   Test 2     C
6    E0303003   Test 2     A
7    E0304005   Quiz 2     D
8    E3306001   Test 1     C
9    E0308002   Quiz 2     A
10   E0301002   Test 2     C
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Thank you for this, but I am having difficulty with it.

If I use the code as supplied, I end up with a full set of data from the left df (df_one) and then nothing but empty columns from df_two to the right.

If I try using an outer join, I get the full left df first, then the full right df below and to the right, like this:
1111111  
1111111  
1111111  
            222222  
            222222  
            222222

Comment: Data are confidental? There are same dtypes of columns for join?

Comment: Got it!  Your solution works fine, it was an issue with my data.  In one file, the Student ID is plain text, and in the other it is hyperlinked text. So they LOOK the same to the naked eye, but when you click into a cell, you can see the text expand to include the http:\\, etc. Thank you for the solution!! I found the other part out from reading this: http://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2014/11/27/when-joins-go-wrong-check-data-types/